# Lodash filter unique then group by on object

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var data = [
   {
      "userCity": "Uttar Pradesh ",
      "userState": "Uttar Pradesh ",
      "AssetId": 53,
      "AssetName": "Parent ID",
      "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"37fb6308-b962-41da-b08f-122ae124500a\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/37fb6308-b962-41da-b08f-122ae124500a/file/maxresdefault.jpg\",\"filename\":\"maxresdefault.jpg\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/jpeg\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
      "AssetSize": "0.088",
      "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
      "AssetType": "image/jpeg",
      "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505129969436.jpg"
   },
   {
      "userCity": "New Delhi",
      "userState": "Delhi",
      "AssetId": 54,
      "AssetName": "PARENT ID TEST",
      "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"150651f1-81be-4059-87b4-f2727f2c5ad6\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/150651f1-81be-4059-87b4-f2727f2c5ad6/file/58832_300x300.jpg\",\"filename\":\"58832_300x300.jpg\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/jpeg\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
      "AssetSize": "0.004",
      "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
      "AssetType": "image/jpeg",
      "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505132244210.jpg"
   },
   {
      "userCity": "Uttar Pradesh ",
      "userState": "Uttar Pradesh ",
      "AssetId": 55,
      "AssetName": "Parent ID ",
      "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"253270a5-f987-445c-959a-be1ba057f7f8\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/253270a5-f987-445c-959a-be1ba057f7f8/file/nodejs-new-pantone-black.png\",\"filename\":\"nodejs-new-pantone-black.png\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/png\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
      "AssetSize": "0.045",
      "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
      "AssetType": "image/png",
      "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505132375228.png"
   }
]
```

I want output with  unique  of AssetId then order By userCity,userState

```
data = [
    city : userCity,
     state : userState ,
     assets:{all details }
]
```

How it is possible with lodash I am tring _.groupBy but not getting desire  output

I tried

```
 users = _.uniqBy(data,'AssetId');
 result = _.groupBy(users, function(o) { return o.userCity; });
```

output

```
{
   "Uttar Pradesh ": [
      {
         "userCity": "Uttar Pradesh ",
         "userState": "Uttar Pradesh ",
         "AssetId": 53,
         "AssetName": "Parent ID",
         "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"37fb6308-b962-41da-b08f-122ae124500a\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/37fb6308-b962-41da-b08f-122ae124500a/file/maxresdefault.jpg\",\"filename\":\"maxresdefault.jpg\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/jpeg\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
         "AssetSize": "0.088",
         "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
         "AssetType": "image/jpeg",
         "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505129969436.jpg"
      },
      {
         "userCity": "Uttar Pradesh ",
         "userState": "Uttar Pradesh ",
         "AssetId": 55,
         "AssetName": "Parent ID ",
         "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"253270a5-f987-445c-959a-be1ba057f7f8\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/253270a5-f987-445c-959a-be1ba057f7f8/file/nodejs-new-pantone-black.png\",\"filename\":\"nodejs-new-pantone-black.png\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/png\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
         "AssetSize": "0.045",
         "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
         "AssetType": "image/png",
         "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505132375228.png"
      }
   ],
   "New Delhi": [
      {
         "userCity": "New Delhi",
         "userState": "Delhi",
         "AssetId": 54,
         "AssetName": "PARENT ID TEST",
         "AssetInfo": "{\"uuid\":\"150651f1-81be-4059-87b4-f2727f2c5ad6\",\"field\":\"file\",\"file\":\"public/150651f1-81be-4059-87b4-f2727f2c5ad6/file/58832_300x300.jpg\",\"filename\":\"58832_300x300.jpg\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"image/jpeg\",\"truncated\":false,\"done\":true}",
         "AssetSize": "0.004",
         "CreatedAt": "2017-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
         "AssetType": "image/jpeg",
         "AssetLocation": "https://ampretailer-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1505132244210.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Put in the question what you do in _.groupBy and what did you get from it.

Comment: Updated question @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi

Answer (score 3):

> Try this it will give output as you want

```
let assets = [];
result = _(results)
         .uniqBy('AssetId')
         .map(function(d){d.city_state = d.userCity +''+d.userState; return d;})
         .groupBy('city_state')
         .forOwn(function(v,k){
              assets.push(v);
         });
```